# How to pass 'quotaUser' parameter for queries to MySQL server in GCP from cloud function?

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, quota

I'm working on a project right now that shows a list of items. To retrieve this data, the page calls a callable cloud function which queries the data from a MySQL server. This MySQL server, like our cloud functions, is part of our project on the Google Cloud Platform.

The page that shows the items is used quite a lot by our customer and last Tuesday they reported some problems that the data wasn't showing or took a long time to show up.
Having looked at the cloud function logs at that time, we see a lot of timeouts followed by a few of these errors:

> CloudSQL warning: your action is needed to update your function and avoid potential disruptions. Please see https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/sql#troubleshooting for additional details: googleapi: Error 429: Quota exceeded for quota group 'default' and limit 'Queries per user per 100 seconds' of service 'sqladmin.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:[some number]'., rateLimitExceeded

I'm not entirely sure if this is the cause of the issue, but it does seem like something we should do something about anyway.
As I understand it, we can send 300 queries per user per 100 seconds to the MySQL server. So about 3 per second. The cloud function itself only sends 2 queries to the server. One to retrieve the data for the current page with the applied filters and another one to get a total record count.
However, we don't send any user info when performing the query. So I think that if 150 users each trigger the callable, 300 queries will be performed and counted towards the quota as if they were done by a single user. Because it's a server, the cloud function, that actually performs the query. The error also mentions the quota group 'default'.

The following page tells me that I should be able to pass a 'quotaUser' parameter to specify a specific user that requests should count towards for the quota.

https://cloud.google.com/apis/docs/capping-api-usage#limiting_requests_per_second_per_user

However... I have no idea how to pass that parameter with our queries. I've read something that this parameter can be used in the url parameters or in the headers, but we are using the Node.js mysql package to perform these queries, and I don't know how to tell it to send this parameter.
This is the guide we followed to set up the mysql connection. We are using the same mysql package.

https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions#node.js

I would think that if a GCP guide tells us to use that mysql package, it should also somehow be possible to specify this quotaUser.

If anyone can help me out with this, it would be greatly appreciated. I'm a bit stuck and can't find any documentation or examples on how to pass this parameter for MySQL queries.

This is how we connect to the MySQL server:

```
import { config } from '../config';
import { createConnection, Connection, ConnectionConfig } from 'mysql';

export function connectToMySQLDatabase(): Connection {
    const connectionName: string | undefined = process.env.INSTANCE_CONNECTION_NAME || `${config.firebaseProjectId}:${config.mysqlConfig.regionId}:${config.mysqlConfig.instanceId}`;
    const dbUser: string | undefined = process.env.SQL_USER || config.mysqlConfig.user;
    const dbPassword: string | undefined = process.env.SQL_PASSWORD || config.mysqlConfig.password;
    const dbName: string | undefined = process.env.SQL_NAME || config.mysqlConfig.databaseName;

    const mysqlConfig: ConnectionConfig = {
        user: dbUser,
        password: dbPassword,
        database: dbName,
        dateStrings: true,
        socketPath = `/cloudsql/${connectionName}`;
    };

    return createConnection(mysqlConfig);
}
```

And how we perform a query:

```
exports.itemQuerySQL = functions
    .region(config.region)
    .runWith({
        timeoutSeconds: 60,
        memory: '1GB'
    })
    .https
    .onCall(async (request: GetItemsRequest, context) => {
        const mysqlConnection: Connection = connectToMySQLDatabase();
        try {
            return await queryItems(request, mysqlConnection);
        } catch (error) {
            throw error;
        }
        finally {
            mysqlConnection.end();
        }
    });

async function queryItems(request: GetItemsRequest, mysqlConnection: Connection): Promise<CallableQueryResponse<string>> {
    let query = '';
    let values = [];

    // Removed a bunch of code irrelevant to the issue that builds up the query and values array.

    const results: any[] = await performQuery(mysqlConnection, sqlQuery, sqlQueryValues);
    return {
        results: results,
        // Some other properties
    };
}

async function performQuery(mysqlConnection: Connection, query: string, values?: (string | string[] | number | null)[]): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve: (value?: unknown) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void): void => {
        mysqlConnection.query(query, values, (error: MysqlError, results: any) => {
            if (error) {
                return reject(error);
            } else {
                return resolve(results);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Besides the code that constructs the query itself, I also left out most of the error handling to keep these examples small.

Comment: Can you share how do you connect your database and how do you use it/interact with it?

Comment: Added the code we use to connect and perform queries to the post.

Comment: How are you invoking the function? Do you perform 300 call in parallel and in the same time?

Comment: We only call this function once when the item overview page is opened / the user changes any filters or goes to the next/previous page. 

However, we do have many users that have access to this item overview. If all of them would be using this page at the same time, opening the page, searching for an item, I have no doubt that it could be invoked 300 times within 100 seconds.

Comment: Do you have other Cloud SQL database in the project? Do you create more than 300 function instances per 100 seconds (load test?)?

Comment: We only have a single SQL database. And looking at the graph of this cloud function, it doesn't exactly look like it's just this one that would be called too much. 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/pddavgs87t8hsmi/itemQueryGraph.png?dl=0

However... we do have like 10 more cloud functions that perform MySQL queries. I'm assuming all of those count towards the quota of the 'default' user. And all of those in total would not surprise me if they exceed that quota.

Answer (score 0):

The quotaUser refers to the end user and is not a quota that is associated with the other GCP products you might be using, so it’s not something that will help you in this issue.

To solve your issue you would need to implement [connection pooling](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/connect-functions#connection-pools). Right now, you are creating a new connection for each request, which causes this quota to be reached faster. By using a connection pool, you will reuse the connections.